# Spyware installed on phone, need to backup data before giving it to police

Tags: backup, data-transfer

A friend of mine installed a spyware on my phone about three years ago, and made the access to that spyware public and i didn't know about it untill recently. I was always confused as to how people know so much about my life and what I say about them to other people. A lot of damage has been caused not just socially but financially as well because the access of the spyware fell into the hands of a scammer who has withdrawn a huge amount of money from my bank account. Now, I want to file a case. Both against that scammer and bastard friend of mine. So, i have been advised to give the phone to the police but because that friend is from a influential family i am under the fear that if I give my phone directly to the police without having a proper backup then they will not find anything because he will get it deleted. So, i want to take a full back-up of the phone. Everything from files to music to apps to system apps so that I can file a case. How can I do that? I need each and every file. So that the police can recover the spyware and then follow up the ip address of the culprits. I need full backup because even if he by influence convinces cyber police department to delete the spyware and say there was nothing in my i would have something to show. Assuming he had not installed the spyware with auto delete feature.